# How to fix "No .NET SDKs were found." error--VSCode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm trying to setup a backend on my local computer I have installed the v6 dotnet everything is installed but when i run `dotnet run`
I get this error

```
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'run' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

dotnet --info

```
PS C:\Users\Az\bazaar-online\Server\Src\BazaarOnline.API> dotnet --info

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.7
  Architecture: x86
  Commit:       0ec02c8c96

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.7 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.7 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

I searched a lot but i didn't find anything useful.
reinstalled everything tried v3 but didn't fix anything

I have installed these files.

```
dotnet-hosting-6.0.7-win
dotnet-runtime-6.0.7-win-x64
dotnet-sdk-6.0.302-win-x64
```

Comment: The files you've listed as installed are a x64 binaries, but your `dotnet --info` reports x86. I would suggest uninstalling everything and then just installing the SDK. The runtime is included with the SDK and the hosting bundle is for servers to host your application.

Comment: You seem to have installed the _runtime_ , not the _SDK_

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ok This fixed the problem for me

I went to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet`

and deleted everthing in the folder

and than vscode recognized the dotnet sdk.

Comment: Wow yes that's it, then I could installed missing visual studio templates

Answer (score 3):

The most voted solution works but is not elegant.

I believe you have installed two versions of dotnet: one for x86 and one for x64, and it resolves the x86 version while the SDK is in x64.

That's why you delete everything in x86 works. Instead, you can adjust the order of the path variable to make the system resolve the x64 version first.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net80 for the details.

Answer (score 1):

The command could not be loaded, possibly because:

- You intended to execute a .NET application:
  The application 'myapp.dll' does not exist.
- You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
  No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
use this commands
1.sudo apt remove dotnet*
2.sudo apt remove aspnetcore*
3.sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
4.sudo apt update
5.sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-6.0

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue when I wanted to install a new template `dotnet new -i "Falco.Template::*"`. Simply reinstalling the dotnet 6 SDK solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting VS Code fixed this for me.