# Trouble running dotnet in vscode after migrating from .net 6.0 to asp.net core 7.0 (Mac / VSCode)

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Trying to migrate from .net 6.0 to  asp.net core 7.0, but my program won't build. I have also tried 'dotnet clean' and changed the `<TargentFramework>net7.0 </TargentFramework>`

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have provided the information from my system along with the warning message I am getting.

Information from `dotnet --info` command

```
Host:
Version 7.0.5
Architecture x64

.NET SDKs Installed:
No SDKs were found

.NET runtimes Installeddotnet --info
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/local/bin/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCORE.App 7.0.5 [/usr/local/bin/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Other architectures found: 
None

Environment variables:
Not set

global.json file:
Not found
```

When I try `dotnet build` I get the following:

```
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
* You intended to execute a .Net application:
The application 'build' does not exist.
* You intended to execute a .Net SDK command:
No .Net SDKs were found
```

Comment: have u checked this bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73247933/how-to-fix-no-net-sdks-were-found-error-vscode possible duplicate

Comment: Are you running an ARM-based mac?

Comment: My mac is AMD based